# Proof that a certain bounded set has no maximum seems wrong

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> if $A = (0, 1)$ then $1$ is the supremum, but there is no maximum!
>   To show this, assume for a contradiction that $x \in A$ is the maximum of $A$. Then also $$(1+x)/2 \in A \quad \quad (1)$$ and $$(1+x)/2 > x \quad \quad (2).$$

I don't see how this is necessarily correct.

It is clear that (1) is correct. How do you deduce that $(1+x)/2 > x$?

$1 + x > x$, is true. $(1 + x) > 1$, true. $(1 + x)/2 > 1/2$, true. How does it follow that $(1+x)/2 > x$ ?

Sorry if this is basic question.

Comment: Take the inequality $1>x$. Add $x$ to both sides. Divide by $2$.

Comment: Something to consider: $(1+x)/2$ is the average of $x$ and $1$.

Comment: You are taking the mean of x and 1. But x is less than 1 so the mean is greater than x.

Comment: Here is another viewpoint: If $x \in (0,1)$ then if $y=x+ {1 \over 2 }(1-x) $ we see that $x<y$ and $y \in (0,1)$. So there can't be a maximum.

Comment: In general $\frac{x+y}2$, the arithmetic mean of $x$ and $y$, is the number halfway between $x$ and $y$. Here you’re getting the number halfway between $x$ and $1$.

Answer (score 4):

From $x<1$ it follows that $2x=x+x<1+x$ and so $x<\tfrac{1+x}{2}$.